# Intermittent access errors when writing to GPIO using SYSFS and Ruby

Tags: gpio, permissions, ruby, sysfs

I am using Ruby to drive output GPIO pins using the old SYSFS pseudo-filesystem interface, and am regularly encountering *intermittent* `Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ rb_sysopen` errors.

My user is a member of the `gpio` group.  The pseudofiles involved are writeable by the `gpio` gpoup.

The following is the simplest failure I've been able to boil it down to (a `pry` session), using a gem called `gpio_sysfs`, which is [an extremely simple wrapper](https://github.com/synthead/gpio_sysfs/blob/main/lib/gpio_sysfs/pin.rb) around reads and writes to files within `/sys/class/gpio/`:

```
[18] pry(main)> p0 = GpioSysfs::Pin.new(0)
#<GpioSysfs::Pin:0x0000005574264408 @pin=0>
[19] pry(main)> p0.value = true
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /sys/class/gpio/gpio0/direction
from /home/slack/.gem/ruby/3.0.3/gems/gpio_sysfs-0.1.0/lib/gpio_sysfs/pin.rb:30:in `write'
[20] pry(main)> p0.direction = "out"
"out"
[21] pry(main)> p0.value = true
true # The output switches high at this point
```

When `p0.value=()` is called, the library first writes to `gpio0/direction` using the same call that I have used on line `[20]`.

Does anybody know why this call fails the first time and succeeds the second?

Hardware is a model 3B and system is a recently installed Raspberry Pi OS Bullseye (64 bit, lite install).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely a timing problem.

There are race conditions with the sysfs.  You need to wait for Linux to set the GPIO to output mode before writing to the GPIO.